# searching record android

Tags: android, sqlite

i m developing android app using sqlite. when i run following lines of code, i received an error.

```
if(student_name.length()>0)
    {

        db.open();

        Cursor c= db.searchByName(student_name);//upto this all is fine

        c.moveToFirst(); //when i debug, i found exception is on this line.

        names=new String[c.getCount()];

        for(int i=0;i<names.length;i++)
            {                   
                    names[i]=c.getString(1);
                    c.moveToNext();                     
            }

        db.close();                              
 }
```

any help will be highly appreciated...

Comment: Please don't keep the error message a secret.

Answer (score 0):

Try parsing your data using a while loop.

```
while(c.moveToNext()){}
```

Without using the `c.moveToFirst()` method!!